# Fortran: Reading unformatted data

Tags: fortran

I have an large txt-file which contains measurements an the longitude/latitude of different stations, like:

```
 1  1 bwb02 52.38783333 13.40266667 LR 0.2
 2  2 bwb04 52.53716667 13.22583333 P1 0
 3  3 bwb05 52.55516667 13.202 SP 0
 4  4 bwb07 52.48433333 13.4385 N1 0
```

I just want to read the 4,5 and 7 column and put them into a matrix, like:

```
  do j = 1,n
   read(12,200) latB,lonB,r
   200 Format (12x,f11.9,1x,f11.9,4x,f5.3)
   beo_data(j,1) = j
   beo_data(j,2) = lonB
   beo_data(j,3) = latB
   beo_data(j,4) = r
  end do
```

But my format isn't working and i get an error:
**Fortran runtime error: Bad value during floating point read**

The problem seems to be that the format of the longitude and latitude is changing.
Could you tell me how i can read and work with such a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read each line as a string using `a` descriptor and then you can read your data using a list-directed read (`*` instead of the format). Or you can use the list directed read directly, if there is no danger of reading from two lines at once.

```
integer :: tmp1,tmp2
character(5) :: tmp3
character(2) :: tmp4
real :: values(3)
  open(12,file="data.txt")
  do j = 1,4
   read(12,*) tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, values(1), values(2), tmp4, values(3)
   print *,values
  end do
  close(12)
end
```

prints

```
   52.3878326       13.4026670      0.200000003    
   52.5371666       13.2258329       0.00000000    
   52.5551682       13.2019997       0.00000000    
   52.4843330       13.4385004       0.00000000
```

Using the fixed column format is useful only when the columns are really fixed.

You can also just use single character variable `tmp` instead of all those different ones.